# Android TOP command CPU usage

Tags: adb, 4.4-kitkat, performance

I'm running a simple command line audio processing program in a shell on my Nexus 10 (Android 4.4.2), and want it to consume 100% CPU while it runs. The reason being, if I know it used 100% CPU, I can compare the time it took to the length of the audio file, and work out the effective CPU load if my program were to run in real time. I have two questions:

- When running TOP on Android, does the value in the CPU column refer to the percentage of one core, or both (my program is single threaded, very simple)?
- When running my program, the CPU shown while it runs is 50%. Is it possible the system is limiting it?

Comment: "When running TOP on Android, does the value in the CPU column refer to the percentage of one core, or both (my program is single threaded, very simple)?" +1. I have a conclusion that it shows percentage of all cores, like Windows, not Linux!

Comment: I ran a stress test on my box https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=skynet.cputhrottlingtest , `top` shows at most 100% CPU.